# Can't display the contents of postgres table in Django Admin panel

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a postgres instance on AWS and I am using it as the database in django. To push the data in the postgres into my django *models.py* I did -

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

The models.py has this -

```
class TasteCluster(models.Model):
    id_cluster = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    table_cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    cluster_description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, 
null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_cluster
```

Now when I check the tables in the admin panel in django I can see the table taste cluster like this -

```
Select taste cluster to change

ADD TASTE CLUSTER
Action:   Go 0 of 8 selected

TASTE CLUSTER
    632
    644
    643
    639
    619
    614
    665
    621
8 taste clusters
```

When I click on any of the id_cluster I get this error -

```
TypeError at /admin/dbconnect/tastecluster/8/change/
__str__ returned non-string (type int)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/dbconnect/tastecluster/8/change/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__str__ returned non-string (type int)
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py in _dec, line 42
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/rahman/Desktop/django_exercise/03project/post',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/rahman/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geos',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.16.3_1/libexec/nose/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.7.1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 25 Jul 2019 16:19:03 +0000
```

How can I get/view all the columns and rows of the table ?

I am a newb at django!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the error says, your `__str__` method is not returning a string, but an integer.

You should return an actual string; no doubt `table_cluster_name` makes the most sense.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.table_cluster_name
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot! I got it. But what if I want display all the columns of the table with the rows in admin panel. How can I do that?

Comment: Use [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).